# Custom TableCellRenderer/TreeTableCellRenderer doesn't render Table cells

Tags: java, swing, renderer, swingx, jxtreetable

I made this `CustomCellRenderer` class intended to be used in `JXTreeTable` and `JXTable` objects since I have many of these in my project. So this class implements `TreeCellRenderer` and `TableCellRenderer` interfaces:

```
public class CustomCellRenderer extends JLabel 
                                implements TreeCellRenderer, TableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        setBackground(selected ? new Color(83,142,213) : Color.white);
        setForeground(selected ? Color.white : Color.black);
        //here is the icon setting code but it's irrelevant to my problem
        setText(value != null ? value.toString() : "<null>");
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setBackground(isSelected ? new Color(83,142,213) : Color.white);
        setForeground(isSelected ? Color.white : Color.black);
        setText(value != null ? value.toString() : "<null>");
        return this;
    }
}
```

And here is the code where I set the renderer:

```
jXTreeTableConsumos.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CustomCellRenderer());
jXTreeTableConsumos.setTreeCellRenderer(new CustomCellRenderer());
```

I'm expecting background and foreground become blue and white respectively when a row is selected. However it only happens at Tree table cell (first column) while only foreground changes and background stills white in the other cells in the very same selected row:

[image]

Could anybody please tell me why cells (that are not tree cells) don't change their background color?

Comment: no entendi la pregunta

Comment: I don't understand, either; why `Object.class`? _what_ doesn't change to blue? Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your comments and suggestions. I found the solution in `JComponent#setBackground(Color bg)` documentation:

> Sets the background color of this component. The background color is
>   used **only if the component is opaque**, and only by subclasses of
>   JComponent or ComponentUI implementations. Direct subclasses of
>   JComponent must override paintComponent to honor this property.

Since my `CustomCellRenderer` extends from `JLabel` the only thing I have to do is make sure it's opaque and its background color will be painted:

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    setOpaque(true);//adding this line I solved my problem
    setBackground(isSelected ? new Color(83,142,213) : Color.white);
    setForeground(isSelected ? Color.white : Color.black);
    setText(value != null ? value.toString() : "<null>");
    return this;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, `DefaultTableCellRenderer` is opaque by default; can it be used in this context?