# How to set custom DefaultTreeCellRenderer at JXTreeTable

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jtreetable, treecellrenderer

I want to set my custom DefaultTreeCellRenderer.

So I have built this class:

```
class CustomTreeTableSpeseXCategoriaSpese extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4842418316518803090L;
    private Font fontTotale = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
    private Font fontNegativo = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
    private int numeroRighe;
    CustomTreeTableSpeseXCategoriaSpese(int numeroRighe){
        this.numeroRighe=numeroRighe;
    }

    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(
            JTree tree,
            Object value,
            boolean selected,
            boolean expanded,
            boolean leaf,
            int row,
            boolean hasFocus) {
        // Allow the original renderer to set up the label
        Component rendererComponent = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(
                tree, value, selected,
                expanded, leaf, row,
                hasFocus); 



        rendererComponent.setBackground( Color.WHITE );
        if (row== this.numeroRighe-1) {
            rendererComponent.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            rendererComponent.setBackground( Color.RED );
            rendererComponent.setFont(fontTotale);
        }else if(row != this.numeroRighe/* && column !=3*/){
            rendererComponent.setForeground( Color.BLACK );
            rendererComponent.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
        }else if(row != this.numeroRighe-1 /*&& column ==3*/){


        }


        return rendererComponent; 
    }
}
```

With this code I can't see my background color, my foreground color.
Another question is, it is possibile to set different Renderer for different column? I want the first 3 column have a background and foreground color, for the other column have a different renderer.

**EDIT**

With that code, I can see the JXTreeTable like this:

[image]

But I want show the TreeTable like this:

[image]

**EDIT**

```
public class CustomTreeTableSpeseXCategoriaSpese extends JLabel implements TreeCellRenderer, TableCellRenderer {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4842418316518803090L;
    private Font fontTotale = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
    private Font fontNegativo = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(isSelected ? new Color(83,142,213) : Color.white);
        setForeground(isSelected ? Color.white : Color.black);
        setText(value != null ? value.toString() : "<null>");
        return this;
    }

    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        //rendererComponent.setBackground( Color.WHITE );
        if (row== tree.getRowCount()) {
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            setOpaque(true);
            setBackground( Color.RED );
            setFont(fontTotale);
        }else if(row != tree.getRowCount()/* && column !=3*/){
            setForeground( Color.BLACK );
            setOpaque(true);
            setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
        }else if(row != tree.getRowCount()-1 /*&& column ==3*/){
            //verifico il valore se negativo rosso
            //se positivo blu
            /*String valore = super.getValueAt(row, column).toString();
            if(valore.startsWith("-")){
                rendererComponent.setForeground(Color.red);
                rendererComponent.setFont(fontNegativo);
            }else{
                rendererComponent.setForeground(Color.blue);
                rendererComponent.setFont(fontNegativo);
            }*/
        }
         setText(value != null ? value.toString() : "<null>");
        return this; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With this code I can't see my background color, my foreground color.

It's hard to tell because you don't show how do you set the renderer to your tree table, which leads to your second question.

> Another question is, it is possibile to set different Renderer for
>   different column? I want the first 3 column have a background and
>   foreground color, for the other column have a different renderer.

A `JXTreeTable` is composed by two parts a tree and a table and thus you have to set both a `TreeCellRenderer` and a `TableCellRenderer` to make custom rendering. Something like this:

```
treeTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CustomTableCellRenderer());
treeTable.setTreeCellRenderer(new CustomTreeCellRenderer());
```

You can make a single class that implements both interfaces as shown in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18253881/1795530)

Comment: I have see that post, but I can't see the change. I have just edit my first questions

Comment: I suspect you are skiping the main part: setting the renderers to your tree table. You still don't show that part in your code just the renderers classes. @bircastri

Comment: Now I can set the renderer for the table part of TreeTable and it's ok. But now I can't set the render of the FIRST column

Comment: The first column is the tree part. Set the tree cell renderer like this: `treeTable.setTreeCellRenderer(new CustomTreeTableSpeseXCategoriaSpese())`. It should work ok. Otherwise include a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. @bircastri

Comment: Yes, I have insert this code, but I can't set correct background color at first column. Now I can set the correct rendere at column 2,3,4 etc, but I can't set renderer at 1 column

Comment: I'd start debuging your renderer because those nested ìf-else` blocks make no much sense to me and supsect the background color is not modified as result of those conditions. You can try applying a default background color regardless the row count just to test the renderer is being applied as expected and then add the conditions as needed. @bircastri

Comment: the debugger it's ok, the problem is at the first column, because I can set the backgroud color only at the JLabel but not at all Column