# Background color to selected item in JList not working

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

Why my selected item background not changing? I surely know that i press list item because my System.out.println says my Current selection and showing id of selected item. No errors no nothing just not working. Why ?

```
 Object[] tablen = sqltable.toArray();
 JList list;
 list = new JList(tablen);                     
 list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
  @Override
  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
   int idx = list.getSelectedIndex();
   setOpaque(true);
    if (idx != -1){
    //list.setSelectionBackground(Color.lightGray);
    // list.setSelectionForeground(Color.lightGray);
    setForeground(Color.red);
    setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
    setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground()); 
    System.out.println("Current selection: " + tablen[idx]);
   }else{
     setForeground(Color.red);
     setBackground(Color.BLUE);
     setBackground(list.getBackground());
     setForeground(list.getForeground());
     System.out.println("Please choose a language."); 
        }
  }                     
});
   list.setCellRenderer(new ListCellRenderer() {
   @Override
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
     String[] val = (String[]) value;
     return new JLabel(val[0]);
    }                           
});
```

Comment: nop i tried this and i cant return c in my cell renderer because if i do that i will lose JLabler return

Comment: also try to read question before marking it as duplicate, not looking at the title as given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware in your cell renderer implementation that `JLabel` is non opaque by default, and probably is the reason why the background color in the list cell renderer is not painted. (see [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18254823/1795530))

On the other hand I'd take a look to [Providing a Custom Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) for a better example on how to implement a custom cell renderer.

Comment: setOpaque(true); was it in my case. Man I hate java gui (mostly because I have no clue of it of course).